# How to allow only 2 groups to use network commands using sudoers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, sudoers

How could I change the sudoers files in order to get both "networkadmingroup" (a group created by me) and the "admin" to use all the network-related commands but not the rest? This is my attempt:

```
Cmnd_Alias WEB = /usr/sbin/httpd, sudoedit /etc/httpd/, sudoedit /etc/init.d/networking

Cmnd_Alias NETWORK_ADMIN = /sbin/ifconfig, /sbin/iptables,WEB

%networkadmingroup ALL = NETWORK_ADMIN
```

If I log in with another user outside of those groups I am however allowed to use those commands. How can I unable them from using them?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like `%othergroup ALL=(ALL) ALL, !NETWORK_ADMIN`. This doesn't stop them from copying the commands somewhere else, though.